# How to get the underlying vector of an IVector<IInspectable>

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I want to use a function that requires me to pass to it as a parameter a void pointer to beginning of a block of memory. The data has to be contiguous in memory for this function to work correctly.

Right now my data is stored in a `IVector<IInspectable>`. Looking at the memory layout of this `IVector` in the debugger I see that there is 28 bytes between my data. Which I *think* are the 7 function pointers from `IUnknown` and `IInspectable`. How can I get the underlying contiguous memory allocation of my data?

**UPDATE**:
Here is the solution I came up with.

Instead of using the `IVector<IInspectable>` I created a custom vector using the `winrt::vector_base` as recommended here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/collections
and I wrapped it in a windows runtime component so that I can use this custom vector from C#.

It looks like this:

MyVector.idl

```
namespace RuntimeComponent1
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass MyVector 
    {
        MyVector();
        void Append(IInspectable in_val);
    }
}
```

MyVector.h

```
// MyVector.h
#pragma once

#include "MyVector.g.h"

namespace winrt::RuntimeComponent1::implementation
{
    using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation;
    using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections;

    struct _MyVector :
        implements<_MyVector, IVector<int>, IVectorView<int>, IIterable<int>>,
        winrt::vector_base<_MyVector, int>
    {
        auto& get_container() const noexcept
        {
            return m_values;
        }

        auto& get_container() noexcept
        {
            return m_values;
        }

    private:
        std::vector<int> m_values{};
    };

    struct MyVector : MyVectorT<MyVector, _MyVector>
    {
        MyVector() = default;
        void Append(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& in_val);
    };
}

namespace winrt::RuntimeComponent1::factory_implementation
{
    struct MyVector : MyVectorT<MyVector, implementation::MyVector>
    {
    };
}
```

MyVector.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "MyVector.h"

using namespace winrt;

namespace winrt::RuntimeComponent1::implementation
{
    void MyVector::Append(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& in_val)
    {
        base_type::Append(winrt::unbox_value<int>(in_val));
    }
}
```

**Example usage:**

C#

```
MyRuntimeComponent.MyVector my_vec = new RuntimeComponent1.MyVector();
my_vec.Append(2);
my_vec.Append(4);

MyRuntimeComponent.MyControl my_control = new RuntimeComponent0.MyControl();
my_control.do_stuff_with_contiguous_memory(my_vec);
```

C++

```
void MyControl::do_stuff_with_contiguous_memory(RuntimeComponent1::MyVector const& in_data)
{
    // Yay data is contiguous
    auto contiguous_data = in_data.as<MyVector>()->get_container().data();
}
```

The end result is that I can pass data from C# to C++/WinRT and the data will be contiguous in C++, which fixes my original problem. It works but I wonder if there might be a simpler / better way?

Comment: There is no requirement that an IVector use a contiguous block of memory at all. If you know that your IVector has a specific concrete representation, you can query for it (such as Platform::Array).

Comment: I just updated my post with the solution I came up with, I'd be curious to hear what you think of it (: